# Replacing Text In a Textbox

Tags: vba, userform

Is there anyway to replace text in a textbox for example see below. I am currently using this, but does not seem to work well in VBA.

```
If TextBox6.Text.Contains("<GTOL-PERP>") Then
    TextBox6.Text = TextBox6.Text.Replace("<GTOL-PERP>", "j")
End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.Text is a string property in VBA.  Strings are not objects in VBA so you'll need to use string functions rather than methods when dealing with them.  See below:

```
If instr(TextBox6.Text, "<GTOL-PERP>") Then
TextBox6.Text = replace(TextBox6.Text, "<GTOL-PERP>", "j")
End If
```

[A List of String Functions in VBA](http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/lrnwdpr/chapter/ch07_03.html)

**EDIT** You can actually skip the IF since replace() doesn't throw an error if the text isn't in the string.